# How to resolve Cannot GET /logout in NodeJS, MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, jwt, ejs

I have a problem, and **I can't resolve the Logout function**. I've referred to different websites and youtube tutorials, but all I see is about logout for Mongo, etc.

In my **"controllers" folder > "auth.js"**, I have a snippet code for the logout session. Basically, it clears the cookie stored. My register and login function works. The logout, on the other hand, is hard.

```
//Logout Session for USER
exports.logout = (req,res) => {
    res.clearCookie('jwt');
    res.redirect('shop/login');
};
```

In my **"routes" folder > "user.js"**, I have this code for logout.

```
router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.login) {
        res.render('shop/profile');
    } else {
        res.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    res.end();
});

//LOG OUT 
router.post('/logout',(req, res)=>{
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect("shop/login");
});
```

And lastly, in **"views" folder > "profile.ejs"**, I have this code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 mt-5">
            <p class="headline2">Welcome!</p>
            <h1><a href="/logout">Log out</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears you export logout from a module. Then, you attempt to access the logOut (different casing) function via req. Do you have some middleware somewhere which attaches the exported logout function to req.logOut?

Comment: Oh, I don't have req.logOut function. Though, I'm starting to progress because Bijay Sharma suggested for GET(logout) instead of POST(logout).

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, Log Out should be GET request instead of POST.

Please update "routes"> folder> "user.js" as follows:

```
router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.login) {
        res.render('shop/profile');
    } else {
        res.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    res.end();
});

//LOG OUT 
router.get('/logout', authController.logout);
```

Please Make sure you have imported the logout() function

Comment: "TypeError: req.logOut is not a function." this is the result, and I'm sorry to ask, but where can I put the "req.logOut" function?

Comment: import logout function. and use logout() instead of req.logOut(). I have updated the code snippet in the answer. Please recheck

Comment: "ReferenceError: logout is not defined" 

I tried to import the code [below] into //LOG OUT,
"router.post('/logout', authController.logout);"

Comment: export the logout middleware then import it in user.js update your router.post('/logout', authController.logout); to router.get('/logout', authController.logout); . If Problem persists then please upload the entire source code.

Comment: The code still has a problem, I could share it to you through GitHub. But it's in a private repository, may I ask for your email/username in GitHub?

Comment: yoursbijay@outlook.com

Comment: Hello, Bijay. I have shared with you our GitHub Repository. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I have updated the logout route. recheck the answer. udate line 61 of user.js with authController.logout();

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearCookie' of undefined" after the authController. I think there's a problem with my exports.logout?

Comment: pass the authController.logout as a middleware

Comment: I think I cracked it! The problem was the res.redirect('shop/login'). I made it into /login a while ago, and thus, the page redirects now.